# how to disable modal popup after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, modal-dialog

I am pretty new to JavaScript and frontEnd, I am trying to build a modal popup which asks for a form submission.Now what I am trying to do is to hide popup as soon the user clicks the submit button.

```js
    function openColorBox(){
        $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"50%", height:"50%", href: "new_greeting_form.html"});
      }
      
      setTimeout(openColorBox, 5000);
    </script>
    <script>
// if you want to use the 'fire' or 'disable' fn,
// you need to save OuiBounce to an object
  var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
  aggressive: true,
  timer: 0,
  callback: function() {  }
  });

  $('body').on('click', function() {
  $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
});

$('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function() {
  $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
});

$('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jackmoore/colorbox/master/example1/colorbox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="\ouibounce.min.css">
    
  </head>
  <body>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    
    <script src="\ouibounce.js"></script>
    <div id="ouibounce-modal">
  <div class="underlay"></div>
  <div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-title">
  <h3>  </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">


  <h2>ThankYou for coming!!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

  </div>
</div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone please help me in this,I'm new and not getting how to proceed in this.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap modal popup which is simple and easy to manage from jquery. For example  `$('#modal').modal('hide');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this line when the user submit the form

```
$('#yourmodal').hide();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,can you also suggest a method in which validation of form data is done then modal popup disappears.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in bootstrap that leaves the background fade in place - you can fix this by also adding the following after the modal hide:

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: But just doing the above did not work, used the below code snippet to make it work. 
`$('#myModalItem').hide(); // Hiding the Modal.
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');         
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$('.myclose').click(); // close button click.
event.stopPropegation(); // Stop further events from happening.`

Answer (score 0):

on submit of your form use the below line to hide.

```
$('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
```